# How to implement an async function with Windows IOCP in Rust?

Tags: rust, async-await

In C#, we can build an awaitable Object with implementing the `INotifyCompletion` interface.

```
public class MyAwaiter<T> : INotifyCompletion
{
    public bool IsCompleted { get; private set; }
    public T GetResult()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    public void OnCompleted(Action continuation)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

But in Rust, I don't know how to build an async function to support operations that are not currently supported in existing asynchronous libraries, such as communicating with low-level devices.

Could you give me an example of self-implementing async function in rust?

Comment: Use [`mio::poll`](https://docs.rs/mio/0.7.0/mio/struct.Poll.html#method.poll). It allows you to write this code portably. On Windows it will be using IOCP under the hood.

Comment: But I have noticed that mio does not have a custom IOCP handler for users.

Comment: Refer to [this issue](https://github.com/tokio-rs/mio/issues/1187)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to implement the `Future` trait on a struct, so let's look at std's definition of `Future`, specifically, it's [`.poll`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/future/trait.Future.html#tymethod.poll) method:

> When a future is not ready yet, poll returns `Poll::Pending` and stores a clone of the `Waker` copied from the current `Context`. This `Waker` is then woken once the future can make progress. For example, a future waiting for a socket to become readable would call `.clone()` on the `Waker` and store it.

One way to use this with some asynchronous mechanism given by the OS would be to send the cloned `Waker` to a newly spawned thread (or ideally, a thread pool where you can enqueue events to wake) that blocks on the event that you set up and calls [`wake()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/task/struct.Waker.html#method.wake) when it's done.

In this example I used sleeping on a thread, but by either using Mio as suggest by a commenter or directly IOCP, you can get pretty similar code, the important aspect is just waking the `Waker` and notifying the `Future` that it happened.

```rust
struct MyEvent {
    is_ready: Arc<AtomicBool>, // Could use a channel to transfer when the task is ready instead
    is_polled: bool,           // Prevents multiple events to get enqueued on the same future
}

impl MyEvent {
    fn new() -> Self {
        MyEvent {
            is_ready: Arc::new(AtomicBool::new(false)),
            is_polled: false,
        }
    }
}

impl Future for MyEvent {
    type Output = ();

    fn poll(self: Pin<&mut Self>, cx: &mut Context) -> Poll<Self::Output> {
        match self.is_ready.load(atomic::Ordering::SeqCst) {
            true => Poll::Ready(()),
            false => {
                if self.is_polled {
                    Poll::Pending
                } else {
                    let waker = cx.waker().clone();
                    let channel = Arc::clone(&self.is_ready);
                    self.get_mut().is_polled = true;
                    thread::spawn(move || {
                        // Here you block based on whatever event
                        thread::sleep(Duration::from_secs(5));
                        channel.store(true, atomic::Ordering::SeqCst);
                        waker.wake();
                    });
                    Poll::Pending
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: I just noticed that you need to update the waker whenever a new poll is made (althought this shouldn't happen with most executors, as they should repoll only when the `Waker` gets woke). The solution isn't trivial and I'd suggest the reader to check the Futures crate in both its source code and the provided channels ([`oneshot`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.4/futures/channel/oneshot/fn.channel.html)) and [`AtomicWaker`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.4/futures/task/struct.AtomicWaker.html), which should make this much simpler. If an actual implementation that works around this issue is requested, I'll try working on a simple POC.